# Generate Backup codes for OTP configured using Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We are using Keycloak v4.5.0.Final and configured OTP for all the users. Is it possible to generate backup codes (like how google does for their dual factor authentication) in case the user doesn't have the Google Authenticator handy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to create your own implementation for OTP authenticator. In my company we customized default **OTP authenticator** and **Configure OTP** required action, so now after OTP initiation user will receive OTP recovery code, that will be stored in his attributes (e.g. Users -> john.doe -> Attributes). Then when user has to provide next OTP code, he also can hit "Lost device" link at OTP code form (we've also customized Keycloak themes) and provide recovery code, and reinstall OTP settings.

[Keycloak customizing docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_development/index.html)